# Is there a way to ensure an open popup is within the view after doing fitbounds

Tags: coffeescript, leaflet

So I have too points:
a = fixed location, with open popup "Destination"
b = user's current location, no popup

I know I can easily call (conceptually)
`map.fitbound([latlng of a, latlng of b])`
and that will zoom my map to contain the two points, the trouble is that it doesn't account for the open popup.  As I have no idea of the user's location, direction from the fix point, or distance, I don't think that using padding possible.

Any hints on how to solve this?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bstreiss/uqzwc9qy/) that demonstrates the issue.

I've looked at couple of the posts about centering popups, but the javascript there is slightly about me, and the js2coffee converter doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explore a solution where popups are always visible without having to move the map.

For example: https://github.com/erictheise/rrose

Here is how I use it: http://franceimage.github.io/map

Move the map to have a marker near an edge, hover or click on it, the popup is always visible.

[image: popup above]
[image: popup right]
[image: popup below]

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I'm looking for.  Didn't think to look in the plugins, as I figured it was just a couple of lines of coffeescript. lol

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think that using padding is possible

[Yes, yes it is](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#fitbounds-options), e.g.:

```
  map.fitBounds(someLatLngBounds, {padding: [100, 100]});
```

See a [working demo](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/lojiw/edit?html,output), and don't forget to [read the docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-fitbounds).

Comment: Thanks @IvanSanchez, perhaps I wasn't clear, I'm sorry.  While I understand how to use padding, it doesn't seem like it's dynamic like fitBounds, or perhaps there's a magic (undocumented) number that you have to have (100 seemed everywhere is was much greater that 25 or 50 I tried).

If I'm in pretty close (like my example) a padding of 50 might look good, but if the user is on the other of the country the popup might be cut off.  Additionally, if the window is sized with a % it becomes even more difficult to select the correct padding.

I had no idea about leaflet playground, thanks. :)

Comment: Apply a padding equal to half the width of the popup. If you know which side the popup will be, apply padding only to that side.

Comment: I tested it with lefleat 1.7.1 and this padding was not working, or zoomed the map to a place where no markers are.

Answer (score 0):

### To have the popups appear in the same position every time

I'm using the following **CSS** solution to fix the popup to *always appear in the same place* where I want it

```html
<style>
    .leaflet-popup {
        transform: none !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 600px !important;
        left: 20px !important;
    }
</style>
```

And then to keep the map from moving every time you click on a marker, set `autoPan` to false in the popup options (https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup-autopan) :

```
 { autoPan: false }
```